# Predict using julia lang MixedModels.jl

Tags: r, julia

I am pretty new to the Julia language (using Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC) Official http://julialang.org/ release x86_64-w64-mingw32 on a Windows 7 machine). I have an R background and found the implementations of mixed models to be slow for very big data sets (n>2,000,000, p > 100). Hence, I searched for alternatives and Julia seems to be lightning fast when it comes to estimation time.

The question I want to raise here is about the MixedModels.jl package of dmbates. Despit its incredible speed compared to, e.g., lme4, I was wondering if there is also some prediction function. Here is a mwe that calls the Dyestuff data from R`s lme4 package:

```
using MixedModels, RCall

R> library(“lme4”)
R> data(Dyestuff)

Dyestuff = rcopy(R"Dyestuff");
mm = fit!(lmm(@formula(Yield ~ 1 + (1 | Batch)), Dyestuff));
```

So how can I do predictions using something like:

`predict(mm, newdata = Dyestuff)`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you care about predictions (to new data) or fitted values? `predict(mm, newdata = Dyestuff)` should yield the same results than `fitted(mm)` in R but is probably slower.

Answer (score 1):

*Please note that Julia has yet to reach v1.0 yet and there are often big, breaking API changes between releases. Likewise `MixedModels.jl` is in active development and must track the Julia API changes in its own API. The information here is (hopefully) correct at the time of writing.*

Looking at the source code for `MixedModels.jl` at the current revision  `e566fcf`, there is no `predict()` method, but there is `fitted()` method which inherits from / overrides `StatsBase.fitted()`. It should be easy enough to also write `predict()` method overriding `StatsBase.predict()` and submit it as a pull request. You might want to look at the [`simulate()` method](https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl/blob/e566fcf/src/simulate.jl#L223-L242) -- instead of generating new data based on existing data, you would use data passed as an argument.

Comment: Hi Livius, thanks for the answer. I would rather wait until dmbates adds a generic `predict()` function, rather than doing it myself.

Comment: You may want to open an issue on the github repo then.